# Flutter app getting too slow when listing pdf

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am listing different files from device storage with changing extension i followed this link for getting files
**link**
[getting files from device](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/20/how-to-list-pdf-files-from-storage-and-view-on-click-flutter-app/)

**function for getting files**

```
 var files;

  Future <void> getFiles() async {
if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
  // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
}
//asyn function to get list of files
List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
var root = storageInfo[0]
    .rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root directory
var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
files = await fm.dirsTree(
    excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/Android"],
   //optional, to filter files, list only pdf files
);
setState(() {}); //update the UI
 }
@override
  void initState() {
getFiles(); //call getFiles() function on initial state.
super.initState();

 }
```

**body**

```
 body:files == null? Text("Searching Files"):
    ListView.builder(  //if file/folder list is grabbed, then show here
      itemCount: files?.length ?? 0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            child:ListTile(
              title: Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
              //   trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: 
             Colors.redAccent,),
              onTap: (){

                }
```

Comment: need more details show how you already implement this & share code

Comment: shared..........